# Deprecated function st_intersection_deprecated_by_postgis_301 problem

Tags: postgis

I was just trying to update postgis after also updating postgresql however I have received the notice that this function, which I use, is now deprecated

Is there a way to keep using it without having to rollback the database?

There isn't anything in the documentation saying that this is now deprecasted

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

Answer (score 2):

The signature of ST_Intersection has changed and it supports now also a third parameter "grid_size"

```
geometry ST_Intersection( geometry geomA , geometry geomB , float8 gridSize = -1 );
```

The update script tries to drop the function with an old signature

```
ST_Intersection(geometry, geometry)
```

but I suppose that your database is using the old version of the function in some view. There is a ticket about the issue https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/5033. It is marked as fixed so I hope that by reading the ticket you can resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've put the update on hold for now but will eventually try it out